# Dropwizard extend @Auth interface

Tags: authentication, dropwizard, access-rights

Does someone know how I can extend the dropwizard interface? Now it just have the required option, but I need to add rights for the anooteted method.

For example:

I have a user admin and a normal user. Both can authenticate and reaches my @auth annotated ressource. But I want to allow some (not all) http method request just for admins and dissalow for normal user. How can I do this outside of ressource? Something like

```
@Auth(required = true, right="admin", httpMethod="POST") User user)
@Auth(required = true, right="normalUser", httpMethod="GET") User user)
@Auth(required = true, right="masterOfTheuniverse",  httpMethod="*") User user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As annotation inheritance is not supported by Java; you can't.

I had a similar case so I had ended up copying the relevant classes from dropwizard and modify as I wished. I've combined [AuthFilter](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-auth/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/auth/AuthFilter.java) with [OAuthCredentialFilter](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-auth/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/auth/oauth/OAuthCredentialAuthFilter.java) as I didn't need the abstraction, and used my own class instead of `Authenticator<C,P>`.

**Note:** I've just realized, they have [rewritten](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/pull/945) the @Auth logic using `RequestFilters` for the next release which looks more flexible and could meet your needs (I might just migrate to that too). The current version (0.8.x) uses `Factory`s, which you can find at [Java8 implementation](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-java8/tree/master/dropwizard-java8-auth/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/java8/auth). Also the [Auth annotation](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/14e73a3007f4a10e40b0b6255217497a9b203d8f/dropwizard-auth/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/auth/Auth.java) which is not in the master branch anymore.

Comment: Now I'm doing the same.